# Less mixin issue for multiple box-shadow arguments

Tags: less, css, stylus

I'm working in a project were i have to use less, personally I always use stylus, but I can't with this project, so I have the next question. how can i do this, that i'm doing with stylus, with less ?  The problem is the number of arguments.

in stylus :

```
box-shadow()
    -webkit-box-shadow arguments
    -moz-box-shadow arguments
    box-shadow arguments

.div {
    box-shadow 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

.div2 {
    box-shadow 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
}
```

output :

```
.div {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.div2 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### LESS now

Current versions of LESS allow you to use commas as separators of lists, and then put a single semicolon at the end of the parameter to pass the whole thing as a comma separated list. So this now works (note the extra semicolon at the end right before the closing parenthesis.

```
.box-shadow(0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2););
                                                                                                                                                                                                        ^here
```

### Original (pre LESS 1.3.3) Answer

Here's how LESS needs to be done to get the same output:

```
.box-shadow(@shadows) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: @shadows;
    -moz-box-shadow: @shadows;
    box-shadow: @shadows;
}

.div {
    .box-shadow(~"0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)");
}

.div2 {
    .box-shadow(0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
}
```

**NOTE:** To do multiple shadows as your `.div`, you need to pass them as a single argument using an escaped string, which is why the first use has `~" "` surrounding the whole argument string. If you are just passing one shadow, that is not necessary. LESS needs that to get the commas between the shadow groups.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Didn't know there was an update that allows you to write with different syntax than the `~""`