# LESS. Comma in the functions

Tags: css, less

I have this function:

```
.box-shadow(@bxsh: none) {
    -moz-box-shadow: @bxsh;
    -webkit-box-shadow: @bxsh;
    box-shadow: @bxsh;
}
```

And i want to accept 2 box-shadows. How can I do it? My variant doesn't work, because comma determined like param separator..

```
.box-shadow(inset 1px 0 0 #4f4f4f, 1px 0 0 #4f4f4f);
```

P.S. Sorry for my English)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9231369/2712740 (the correct answer is in question itself), Docs: http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-mixins-with-multiple-parameters.

Comment: [This answer illustrates it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400737/less-mixin-issue-for-multiple-box-shadow-arguments/15406343#15406343)